# Check for string length in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a program that get 2 strings from the user and compare the 2 given strings by their length and return the longest string..

As you can see it's not finished because I have a problem with the length counting:

```
# longestChar

.macro Terminate
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    .end_macro

.data
s1: .space 100
s2: .space 100

l1: .word 0
l2: .word 0

m1: .asciiz "Enter First String:\n"
m2: .asciiz "Enter Second String:\n"

.text
main:
    la $a0, m1
    jal printString
    la $a0, s1
    li $a1, 101
    jal scanString
    la $a0, m2
    jal printString
    la $a0, s2
    li $a1, 101
    jal scanString
    la $a0, s1
    jal stringLength
    sw $t0, l1

    Terminate

printString:
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    jr $ra

scanString:
    li $v0, 8
    syscall
    jr $ra

stringLength:
    li $t0, 0
    stringLength_loop:
        lb $t1, 0($a0)
        beqz $t1, stringLength_exit
        addi $a0, $a0, 1
        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j stringLength_loop
    stringLength_exit:
        jr $ra
```

The problem is I always get 1 more than the actual length. So, if the string is `Hello World` I get `12` instead of `11`.

Please Help ?

Comment: The code as shown works and gives 11. Whatever you are doing wrong is elsewhere.

Comment: @Jester I edited it to the full code

Comment: You're probably counting the ending newline character (ASCII 10).

Comment: @Michael OK, How can I solve this ?

Comment: Add a check to stop at newline too.

Comment: i'll appreciate it if someone can give me an example of how to do it and not just instruction, cause I really don't know how..

Comment: Do you have problem comparing a register with a number?

Comment: Do you know, what the current instructions in stringLength do?